# Managing Apache to Compensate for WebDAV's Security Masking

Tags: apache-2.2, security, webdav

When a user creates a file via WebDAV, the default behavior is that the file is owned by the user and group running the Apache process, with a umask of 022.

Unfortunately, this makes it impossible for unprivileged users to write to the files by other means without being a member of the group Apache runs under (which strikes me as a particularly bad idea).

My current solution is to set `umask 000` in Apache's envvars and remove all world permissions from the webdav parent directory for the user. So, if the WebDAV share is `/home/foo/www`, then /home/foo/www is owned by `www-data:foo` with permissions of `770`. This keeps other unprivileged users out, more or less, but it's hokey at best and a security disaster awaiting at worst.

From my research and poking around at mod_dav and Apache, I cannot find a reasonable solution short of a cron job flipping all the permissions back (I'd rather not have the load and increased complexity on the server). SuExec won't work, either, because WebDAV operations are not going to execute as a different user.

Any thoughts on this? Thank you.

Comment: My thought, is that Apache doesn't really do very well as a WebDAV server.  I really wish there was something better, but I haven't found it.

Comment: Likewise, Zoredache. I've been looking, but I haven't found anything really satisfactory. It would be nice if there were a solid WebDAV server that ran isolated and could either run MPM-style or grant correct permissions (or at least leave them alone).

EDIT: There was an MPM Apache many moons ago, but no development has happened on that in a long time. At least with that I could fork out the Apache instances as each user and utilize mod_dav under each child.

Comment: I would prefer a real WebDAV file server as well, but there is a solution. See my answer here: http://serverfault.com/a/457299/50950

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I circumvented Apache's lack of user switching capabilities by using Posix ACL. These allow you to add more group and user entries on every file and also allow setting up default permissions on directories which are automatically added to each file created within.

If I guess right and you're running Linux, you can enable Posix ACL you need to remount you file system with the `acl` option. Then you can use `setfacl` and `getfacl` to manage additional permissions. On Debian-based systems these tools can be found in the package `acl`. You can further read about Posix ACL in `man acl` and `man setfacl`. Posix ACL are also available on some BSD systems and MacOS, but I never used them there.

For example you could set up a folder in which group `fileserver` always has read and write access to all files within:

```
setfacl -Rm default:group:fileserver:rw,group:fileserver:rx /srv/fileserver
```

That would result in `getfacl /srv/fileserver` reporting something like this:

```
# file: /srv/fileserver
# owner: aef
# group: aef
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:fileserver:r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:fileserver:rw-
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

A warning though: You will probably need some time to get used to Posix ACLs, they add quite a bit more complexity, even as it doesn't seem so at first.

Comment: Thank you aef! This seems very promising and I will try this as soon as I am able. I will reserve marking it as the answer until then, but I will try to get that done sometime in the next few days. Thank you.